# issues with Puppet module to install Vagrant and plugins

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, vagrant, puppet, provisioning

I'm trying to write a Puppet module to install Vagrant and a couple associated plugins. However, when I provision the machines with Puppet, Vagrant installs correctly but the `vagrant-aws` plugin installation fails. I use an exec resource with the command `vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws` which executes fine when run from the command line on the machine, but when run through Puppet it fails with errors. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What errors it produce?

Comment: Downvote: Needs more illustration.

Comment: We need to see your Puppet module and the error output. One possibility that comes to mind is that your exec resource does not require Vagrant to be installed already. However, that's just a hunch without any details to go on.